# Google Analytics trackers versus dimensions

Tags: google-analytics

Just getting started with GA. I've read about custom dimensions and metrics, but also about "trackers". They seem to do the same thing and yet I can't find any reference on how they are different, why there are both.

Comment: For example, here are the two definitions provided in GA help: Custom dimensions and metrics are a powerful way to send custom data to Google Analytics.

Tracker objects (also known as "trackers") are objects that can collect and store data and then send that data to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trackers are the overall objects that Google Analytics uses to capture all tracking activities, be it custom metrics, dimensions etc.

Custom metrics and dimensions are objects that are set on a tracker, to be sent to your GA account.

The syntax is similar to setting custom metrics I suppose, but the sytax for all GA tracking is fairly similar for ease of development.

Comment: So why would someone use both? Or wouldn't they? I see that custom dimensions are limited to 20. Trackers seem like a way around that limitation maybe?

Comment: You always have to use a tracker to send any data, custom or not. Custom dimensions are optional. If you use two trackers, you could have 20 custom dimensions in each, but the data is "unlinked" - each tracker is like the data bucket of data.

Comment: Does data sent using a tracker appear in the GA UI just like custom dimensions? Are dimensions just a lite version of trackers for non-programmers?

Comment: All data is sent via a tracker.  The documentation here pretty much says "set up a tracker, then send pageviews with that tracker": https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ - custom dimensions are another thing you can send with the tracker.  See also here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets - note that sending a custom dimension is almost the same as a pageview.

Comment: Yep, I've seen all that. Like I said it doesn't really mention a difference. But maybe this is it: "Custom dimension or metric data may only be sent with an existing hit".  And maybe piece of data sent through a generic tracker (not associated with a defined dimension, something you have to configure ahead of time) doesn't have this limitation - can send apart from an existing hit. Anyways, thanks.